# HTML to PDF conversion using Chrome pdfium

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, pdf-generation

Can anyone suggest how to convert HTML to PDF using chrome pdfium.

Since, I tried pdf.js and few other, but It is not giving me a proper result.

I think chrome pdfium handle them properly. So, I would like to give a try to pdfium for generating PDF file from HTML source.

Thanks.

Answer (score 58):

[PDFium](https://code.google.com/p/pdfium/) (and [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)) are merely PDF Viewers, you cannot convert HTML to PDF with them.

The actual PDF generation in Chrome is done by the [printing component](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/components/printing) using [Blink](https://www.chromium.org/blink) (the rendering engine) and [Skia](https://code.google.com/p/skia/) (the graphic stack). There is an effort going on to decouple the printing functionality from the printing UI so that third-party projects can use the printing functionality ([crbug.com/311308](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=311308)), but it is still work-in-progress.
**Chrome 59** and up can be used to convert HTML to PDF, via the `--print-to-pdf` flag. See [crbug.com/603559](https://crbug.com/603559) for the specific feature itself, and  https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md for documentation about headless Chromium in general. This example loads example.com and outputs the result to `path/to/file.pdf.

```
chrome --headless --print-to-pdf=path/to/file.pdf https://example.com
```

If you want to know how to use Chrome's built-in PDF generator in JavaScript, follow the following question (which has not been answered yet): [Javascript call programmatically the "Save as PDF" feature of Chrome dialog print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096749/javascript-call-programmatically-the-save-as-pdf-feature-of-chrome-dialog-prin).

Comment: The URL to headless Chrome documentation is https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md

Comment: @pfurbacher Thanks. I've put a space between my link and the next word to fix the link.

Comment: This is awesome! But how to send print parameters via CLI like "No Border", "Keep Background Graphics"...?

Comment: FYI printing to pdf does not work well where the HTML contains async loading of scripts and the like

Comment: Man I went into a deep rabbit hole that started wanting to convert a div element to pdf in my electron app i tried a lot of js libraries they all don't make a pixel-perfect output of the pdf, now I am here. I hop this works and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a prebuilt library like my [html-pdf-chrome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf-chrome) to generate a PDF from HTML using Chrome.