# How does Chrome render PDFs from HTML so well?

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf, webkit

I'm looking to emulate some of Latex's features in HTML and render to PDFs. So far, I've come very close using Chrome's "save to PDF" print feature.

I've tried [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) (not great), [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (OK), Safari (pretty good) and Firefox (almost there) but none come close to Chrome's quality.

There are a lot of details that only Chrome gets right, even though most options run off webkit e.g. font rendering soft-hyphens, math symbols with MathJax and specifying page options like A4 and marginless etc.

What is Chrome's "secret sauce" and how can I get hold of it to automate this process?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A fairly comprehensive answer was found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28096322/1816242

PDFium is the PDF *viewer* used in Chrome. The **printing component** is a combination of Blink and Skia.

[These guys](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=311308) are working on refactoring the printing components which could lead to an eventual API / automation for PDF generation.

Answer (score 0):

From the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/pdf/&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&q=pdf),  it looks like they are using [PDFium](http://code.google.com/p/pdfium/), which derives from [Foxit Reader](http://blog.foxitsoftware.com/foxit-pdf-technology-chosen-for-google-open-source/). Either the PDFium code or the Foxit PDF SDK might help automate.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I actually found an even more comprehensive answer already on stackoverflow by searching for PDFium from your answer.