# How can I programmatically save HTML/CSS as a PDF using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I'm using OS X and I see on chrome that I can Save as PDF in the print window if I set the destination to "Save as PDF". Does this functionality exist in Windows?

Is there any way I can take advantage of this and have it save to PDF with just a click of a button? How can I open up the print page and save that as a PDF? Can I set the default destination to "Save as PDF" and then programmatically click the "Save" button?

Edit: I have tried to use jsPDF but was unable to pull the CSS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript call programmatically the "Save as PDF" feature of Chrome dialog print](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096749/javascript-call-programmatically-the-save-as-pdf-feature-of-chrome-dialog-prin)

Answer (score 1):

there is also an option to print PDF on Windows 10.
This javascript code opens a print dialog:

```
window.print();
```

Comment: I can get the print window to pop up on both Mac and Windows, but how can I set the default print destination to "Save as PDF?" From here how can I use javascript to click "Save?"

Answer (score 0):

I have used [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) before to render PDFs from webpages programmatically.  You'd have to write a PhantomJS script to accomplish that but they have helpful examples documented.

Comment: Important: PhantomJS development is suspended until further notice (more details).
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344

Answer (score -1):

[jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) is a good tool for this.

This question is a possible duplicate of [Download a div in a HTML page as pdf using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293135/download-a-div-in-a-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript), which provides a demo and sample usage for jsPDF.

Comment: Please don't write an answer pointing to a duplicate. Instead, click the flag link under the question and select the duplicate reason.